# Figures with same figure numbers

Tags: floats, numbering

Is it possible to have 2 figures with the same figure number in LaTex? I am using texstudio as my editor.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Yes, this is possible, but why do you want to have two identical figure numbers? This will confuse readers and makes cross-referencing difficult. (The information about TeXStudio` is not really important, that's an editor only

Comment: see if `\ContinuedFloat` from package caption can help you. for moreparticular help please provide minimal working example (a small, complete document, which show what you try so far)

Comment: If the figures are meant to have the same caption, put them both in the same `figure` environment.

Comment: Right now, the question is of poor quality. Though there is an answer, a bit more context in the question would be nice. Depending on what you want, there are different solutions, the one below not being the very best. Please update the question by editing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the subsequent figure to have the same number of the previous figure, a simple way of doing it is with

```
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
```